# What is | in C# here?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, aspose.words, bitwise-or

In the following code block there are a few bitwise OR's. I've never used them before so I was trying to understand what the code block meant.

```
    Document doc = new Document("CleanupOptions.docx");
    doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions = MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedRegions |
    MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedFields |
    MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveContainingFields;
    doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dataSet);
```

So in that block above, if I used doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions, how would I pick any of the statements that the CleanupOptions are equal to? Or are they all combined?

Comment: This Q/A has a good explanation of enumerations with [Flags]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Comment: it's about [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc138362.aspx)

Comment: Assuming that `CleanupOptions` is a bitfield enumeration, this simply concats the constants...

Answer (score 0):

They are all combined. An enum can be marked with the [FlagsAttribute] which allows combination of values:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MailMergeCleanupOptions is an enum with the FlagsAttribute specified.  This allows you to do bit-wise ors to join the values into a collection.  Normally the values are powers of two or a combination of flags.

Comment: It's not really the `[Flags]` attribute doing that though, that attribute does very little. It's the enum itself combined with how it is interpreted by the consuming code.

Comment: The compiler will complain if you do a bitwise or on an enum that does not have the [Flags] attribute.

Comment: No it doesn't, you even made me doubt myself enough that I went to try it

Comment: Must be ReSharper that complains.  Sometimes I lose track which one is generating which warnings.